# Poner navbar collapsible para tablet con Bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, navbar

Tengo mi `navbar`de Bootstrap (versión 3.4.0) que en dispositivos móbiles (< 768px) cambia para ser collapsible. Quisiera hacer que esta misma manera se mantenga para tamaño tablet (< 1024px), pero al superar los 768 px, el `navbar` cambia al estilo para desktop.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo editando solamente el css y sin tener que editar y compilar el código de Bootstrap? 
Dejo el código de mi barra de navegación.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="menu" style="background-color: red">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle x collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-x">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"> <img src="imgs/logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo"></a>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-x">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="active" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse.in"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>

<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse.in"><a href="#pag1">Pagina 1</a></li>

<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse.in"><a href="#pag2">Pagina 2</a></li>

<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse.in"><a href="#pag3">Pagina 3</a></li>

<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse.in"><a href="#pag4">Pagina 4</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: He intentado con unas soluciones en otras respuestas, en las que te aconsejan modificar el código de Bootstrap, compilarlo y descargarlo, pero no me funcionó

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es cargar primero tu hoja de estilos personalizada en la que apliques el cambio del breakpoint de Bootstrap. No sería lo más limpio, pues creas duplicidad, pero es lo que yo haría si no puedes o quieres tocar la hoja de estilos de Bootstrap.

Comment: Algo como esto: https://www.codeply.com/go/VsYaOLzfb4 Sólo cambia el breakpoint de 1200 a 1024

Comment: @JheymanMejia he intentado eso. Funciona, pero no del todo bien, ya que parece que me modifica los estilos que le puse a la barra. Y no sé cómo hacer para volver a ponerlos, porque algunos estilos no me los toma

Comment: Pásate por el chat, podemos probar varias cosas para lo que necesitas https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96496/sala-de-ayuda-programacion